# How can i check if every object in my ArrayList has a value equal to zero?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a game and need to check if all players in the playerList have played all their games. I do this by taking away from the noOfGames variable until it is 0. My problem with my code right now is that if the last player in the playerList have finished, the game ends. Here is my code:

```
public boolean isGameOver(){
        boolean allEqualsZero = true;

        for(Player i : playerList){
            if (i.getNoOfGames() != 0){
                allEqualsZero = false;
            }
            else{
                allEqualsZero = true;
            }
        }
        return allEqualsZero;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `boolean` variable may change for each player.

The game is over if someone has something to play, so if someone still has to play, directly return `false`.

If no one has something, return `true` at the end.

```
public boolean isGameOver() {
    for (Player i : playerList) {
        if (i.getNoOfGames != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

You may otherwise use a `stream` if you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
public boolean isGameOver(){
    return playerList.stream()
                     .allMatch(x -> x.getNoOfGames() == 0);
}
```

Comment: that java-8 tag in there is so boss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that it returns whether **the last player** equals to `0`. So what you should do, is if any one player equals to `0` return `false`, otherwise return `true`, something like that:

```
for(Player i : playerList){
    if (i.getNoOfGames() != 0) return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it, is by using Java 8 Streams:

```
public boolean isGameOver(){
   return playerList.stream().allMatch(player -> player.getNoOfGames() == 0);
}
```

`allMatch` will take a function that will check all the players if the number of games is 0 and return true only if all are 0.

Check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) for more information.

Comment: I think you mean `allMatch(Predicate<T>)`

Comment: Indeed!  Dunno how I got that mixed up.